# Why is it showing on the console that React doesn't recognize the startAdornment prop on a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use `InputAdornment` from MUI but the console keeps showing  that React doesn't recognize the `startAdornment` prop on the DOM element.

```
import { Stack, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import InputAdornment from "@mui/material/InputAdornment";

export const MuiText = () => {
  const inputProps = {
    startAdornment: <InputAdornment position='start'> $ </InputAdornment>
  };

  return (
    <Stack spacing={4}>
      <Stack spacing={2} direction='row'>
        <TextField label='a' variant="filled" required color='success' />
        <TextField label='b' variant='outlined' inputProps={inputProps} />
        <TextField label='c' variant="standard" type="password" />
      </Stack>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

And I am expecting it to render an input field with $ sign from the start.

Comment: `InputProps`, not `inputProps`. Case is extremely important =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  Which input are you saying should be capitalized and why?

Comment: @MHYAnate Post the errors you're getting

Answer (score 0):

`InputProps` should be capitalized. You can modify the code to make it look like this:

```
import { Stack, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import InputAdornment from "@mui/material/InputAdornment";

export const MuiText = () => {
  const InputProps = {
    startAdornment: <InputAdornment position='start'> $ </InputAdornment>
  };

  return (
    <Stack spacing={4}>
      <Stack spacing={2} direction='row'>
        <TextField label='a' variant="filled" required color='success' />
        <TextField label='b' variant='outlined' InputProps={InputProps} />
        <TextField label='c' variant="standard" type="password" />
      </Stack>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

`inputProps` and `InputProps` are different.

Visit https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field for more infos